# How to find the number of pages in a multi page tiff file when the pages are saved in strips

Tags: c++, c, tiff, libtiff

I want to read a multi-page TIFF file with the libtiff library. Put it into a 1D array and do processing on it. The TIFF file is saved in strips of 6 lines, where each line has 600 pixels  each defined with a 2 byte (uint16) value. In each page there are 100 lines for example, and lets say we have 3 pages. 
These were the numbers for one example.

To be able to generate the 1D array, I think I need to allocate memory for the image to put the values in that memory, however I do not know the dimensions of the TIFF images and so with: `TIFFGetField(tif1, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &width)`, I can find the width of one image and with: `TIFFGetField(tif1, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &height)`, I can find the height of the image.

But how should I find the number of the pages to allocate the right amount of memory in advance?

Comment: Are the strips vertical or horizontal?  Does the format have one strip for all pages, then comes back and does 2 row for all pages?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am pretty new to using libtiff and I do not know how to make sure about that. However I have used these commands stripSize = TIFFStripSize(tif); and numstrips=TIFFNumberOfStrips(tif). So it has stipsize=7200-->(6lines of 1200 bytes(600pixels)) and numstrips=17 From these values, it seems that the data saved and read in the first directory is equal to the data amount that I expect for one page. So I think the pages are saved one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the [TIFF specification](http://www.libtiff.org/document.html), you have an image in each TIFF Directory.

By using `int TIFFReadDirectory(TIFF* tif)` you go to the next TIFF Directory and then can read the next image.

Hence, you can allocate the amount of memory needed for each image, each time you read one.

The following code permits you to iterate through all the directories of your TIFF file :

```
#include "tiffio.h"
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen(argv[1], "r");
    if (tif) {
    int dircount = 0;
    do {
        dircount++;
    } while (TIFFReadDirectory(tif));
    printf("%d directories in %s\n", dircount, argv[1]);
    TIFFClose(tif);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

In the `do-while` loop you could add your image reading.